# Move a GitHub project card when a branch is pushed with the issue number

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub project where cards appear in the `To do` column when an issue is opened. Now, I would like to move those cards when the issue number they are linked to is present in the name of the branch pushed to GitHub.

Is that at all possible?
If not what's another flow we should consider where automation is possible?